# How to use an API on an android apps?

Tags: c#, android, api, xamarin

I am new to app development and I am trying to create an app that will have someone log into their Instagram account and in the app you will be able to view your own pictures.

https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/?hl=en

This website shows us how to do that but it says I need to redirect them back to my URL, but the problem is that android apps don't have url's.

Am I missing something? How should I go about this? Do I have to create a website for the app?
Thanks!

Also, I am using Xamarin to develop this app in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Instagram uses OAuth 2.0 https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/?hl=en you can use Xamarin.Auth component https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth to simplify the implementation. It will do all the required work for you :)

But the idea is simple - in your mobile app you open this url https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code in a WebView control, user is authenticated on the web-site and the user is navigated to a special url. You intercept navigation and parse the url to get the auth token which you can use later to execute requests to the service.

EDIT

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
               clientId: "CLIENT_ID",
               scope: "basic",
               authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/"),
               redirectUrl: new Uri ("REDIRECT_URL"));

auth.AllowCancel = allowCancel;

// If authorization succeeds or is canceled, .Completed will be fired.
auth.Completed += (s, ee) => {
    var token = ee.Account.Properties ["access_token"];
};

var intent = auth.GetUI (this);
StartActivity (intent);
```

Comment: Thanks, so I looked at the link for xamarin.auth, and It shows me how to authenticate the user and how to make requests, but I do see the part where I get the code and exchange it for access token. I tried parsing the url in the webview but it didnt work.Sorry for the dumb question but how should I do this ?

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to get token. Don't forget to uncheck "Disable implicit OAuth" in your client's security settings on the Instagram site.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really related to Xamarin because with Xamarin you use C#. So what you are looking for is how to use the Instagram API with C#. Maybe that sample on [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Haroon-Said-e1d8d388) will help you to understand the steps needed to get started.